# C# WebApi AttributeRouting ; also possible to specify optional nullable integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, int, nullable, attributerouting

Following this page : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

These routes are supported:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}")]
public ActionResult GetUserById(int id) { . . . }

[Route("users/{id?}")]
public ActionResult GetUserById(int? id) { . . . }
```

But it seems that **optional Nullabble< int >** is not supported:

```
[Route("users/{id:int?}")]
public ActionResult GetUserById(int? id) { . . . }
```

Is there a way to use this ?

Comment: Whats wrong with the second method in the first code block? I dont know squat about routing, but both the supported and unsupported methods use `int?` and the supported one is, well, supported.

Comment: If im totally misreading something, is it possible to do `id:int?`

Comment: @BenKnoble ; I've updated the code.

Comment: OP refers and optional type `int?` where the type could be an *integer* or `null`. I think this is a classic **xy problem**. Can you please explain the problem and not your desired solution?

Comment: I understand that `int?` can be int or null; i dont see any difference in the declarations of the two methods other than the attributes. My question is, whats wrong with the one that works?

Comment: I can make this route, and it works fine, maybe there is some other issue you are experiencing?... `[Route("testmethod/{id:int?}")] public string TestMethod(int? id)`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.  I suspect there's something else going on, as MVC5 lets you plug that in as a route, no problem, and resolves it.  Now, having both routes in there won't work, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do, is it?